# How to integrate the product of two functions

Tags: r, calculus

Suppose I am seeking to integrate the following function from 0 to 10:

[image]

How would I accomplish this in `R`?

**Functions**

```
# Functional form
fn <- function(t) -100*(t)^2 + 20000

# First derivative w.r.t. t
fn_dt <- function(t) -200*t

# Density funciton phi
phi <- approxfun(density(rnorm(35, 15, 7)))

# Delta t
delta <- 5
```

Comment: *"integrate the following function"* Integrate which function? Of which variable? Over which interval?

Comment: Also: What's `approxfun`? Is that a custom function? A function from an external R library?

Comment: @MauritsEvers  It is from `stats`

Comment: @akrun Damn, my bad. Never came across `approxfun`. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

1. First off, we choose a fixed seed for reproducibility.

   ```
   # Density funciton phi
   set.seed(2017);
   phi <- approxfun(density(rnorm(35, 15, 7)))
   ```
2. We define the integrand.

   ```
   integrand <- function(x) {
       f1 <- -500 * x^2 + 100000;
       f2 <- phi(x);
       f2[is.na(f2)] <- 0;
       return(f1 * f2)
   }
   ```

   By default, `approxfun` returns `NA` if `x` falls outside the interval `[min(x), max(x)]`; since `phi` is based on the density of a normal distribution, we can replace `NA`s with  `0`.
3. Let's plot the `integrand`

   ```
   library(ggplot2);
   ggplot(data.frame(x = 0), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun = integrand) + xlim(-50, 50);
   ```

[image]

4. We use `integrate` to calculate the integral; here I assume you are interested in the interval `[-Inf, +Inf]`.

   ```
   integrate(integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)
   #-39323.06 with absolute error < 4.6
   ```