# non-numeric argument to binary operator in integration in R

Tags: r

```
f1 = function(t){exp(-t^2)} 
phi1 = function(theta){
     0.5-1/sqrt(pi)*integrate(f1, lower = 0, upper = (10-theta)/(2*sqrt(2)))}  
mu1 = (450*barx)/(454)  
sigs1 = 36/454 
pi_thetapost = function(theta){
     (1/sqrt(2*pi*sigs1))*exp(-((theta-mu1)^2)/(2*sigs1))}  

E_phipost = integrate(phi1*pi_thetapost, lower = -Inf, upper =Inf)
```

I was trying to do a integration, and I got the error says: 
`non-numeric argument to binary operator`
I think that `*` is a binary operator, but I am not sure how to figure this out.

Thanks~

Comment: @Esther Thank you! I was trying to integrate the product of `phi1` and `pi_thetapost`.

Comment: Does this question help? [how to integrate the product of two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828266/how-to-integrate-the-product-of-two-functions)

Comment: @Esther I just tried the method in the link, still got the same error. Is that because my `phi1` is a function contains an integration?

Comment: Yes look at what the call to `integrate` returns, (an object of class 'integrate'). I think you will need to extract the `value` from that object and then do the next operation. When you integrate the products of those functions, I think you will need to wrap them in a single function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few problems here. First `barx` isn't defined. But the main problem is that you can't just multiple functions in R. You can multiple the values returns by function, but not the functions themselves. You need to pass in a proper function to integrate.

But then after that problem, you need to make sure all the functions you pass in to integrate() are vectorized and your `phi` function is not. you need to be able to pass in a vector and get a vector out. The easiest way to fix this is with `Vectorize()`. And finally, `integrate()` returns an object, not just a number. So if you want to return the calculated value, you need to extract it from the object before you can multiply it by another object. Try

```
f1 <- function(t){
  exp(-t^2)
} 
phi1 <- function(theta) {
  0.5-1/sqrt(pi)*integrate(f1, lower = 0, upper = (10-theta)/(2*sqrt(2)))$value
 }  
barx <- 2 # or whatever
mu1 <- (450*barx)/(454)  
sigs1 <- 36/454 
pi_thetapost <- function(theta){
  (1/sqrt(2*pi*sigs1))*exp(-((theta-mu1)^2)/(2*sigs1))
}  
myfun <- function(x) {
  Vectorize(phi1)(x)*pi_thetapost(x)
}
E_phipost <- integrate(myfun, lower = -Inf, upper =Inf)
E_phipost
# 3.690467e-05 with absolute error < 5.6e-05
E_phipost$value
# [1] 3.690467e-05
```